# COSMOS public instance - ssh to Head node

Tags: fiware, filab, cosmos

I have read COSMOS documentation and [the wiki](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers#Step_1._Create_a_Cosmos_account).

I can login at http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org/cosmos-gui, but when I try to

ssh pablo@cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org

I get a "Permission denied" with my credentials.

I have tried both ssh form my machine and form a Orion VM instance. I get the same result.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have realize that COSMOS public instance creates new users according the email at loging (name@server.com -> user:'name'). 

What happens if two fi-lab users request COSMOS access? 
For example name1@server1.com and name1@server2.com.

Comment: As I've told you in a private email, this is definitely a bug that must be solved. In the meantime, you can use the other user account you told me you tried to create (and that I've completed manually, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302418/safemodeexception-at-cosmos-lab-fi-ware-org/28314846#28314846)).

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302418/safemodeexception-at-cosmos-lab-fi-ware-org/28314846#28314846